# UITableView titleForHeaderInSection is big and a different font

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm trying to get it to look just like the settings page. However, when I add a title to the header, it looks like the font is : bold, comic sans, and 18pt. Any ideas?

I tried both the storyboard and code below:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return ("hi")
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can implement UITableView optional method viewForHeaderInSection and return a custom Label with your desired font and size

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
```

If you need to specify a different height for your Header in section you need to implement optional method heightForHeaderInSection as well.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat
```